# How to check NSXmlParser finished parsing?

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

In my project I am consuming web services and parsing data from web services in another class and showing this data in a tableView it works absolutely fine in synchronously but 
I have tried to implement it a asynchronously and it is not showing data although data has been received as it is showing on Console when I restart the app on simulator it will show if I wait it until to show on console is there any way to check data is available to show on tableView so as I can reload tableview to display data

Comment: R u using NSXMLParserDelegate in your class??

Comment: You should accept some of your questions as answers if you want folks to continue to help ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use the NSXMLParserDelegate in your class you can find it out through the following delegate method

```
//Called when the XML document has been finished parsing
    - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
    {

    }
```